# Wrong event time in CloudWatch log events

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Found the solution after searching, but leaving this here if somebody happens to run into similar kind of confusion. See resolution in the end.

I'm trying to figure out why AWS CloudWatch log service fails to understand the right timestamp for my log events. Currently all my events are being saved under Time 2017-01-01 no matter what the actual timestamp in the event is.

I'm feeding the log from syslog where docker is saving the logged events and I configured docker to put the timestamp in format:

```
170105/103242 (%y%m%d/%H%M%S)
```

I configured awslogs service with parameters:

```
datetime_format = %y%m%d/%H%M%S
```

I restarted the service and hit the server, but still when I go to CloudWatch and see the log entries, even entries that indeed start with timestamp 170105/103242 are actually saved as events that belong to date 2017-01-01 containing all events between 01-01 and 01-05

When I look at the awslogs.log I can see following lines:

```
2017-01-05 11:05:28,633 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 29223 - MainThread - Missing or invalid value for use_gzip_http_content_encoding config. Defaulting to using gzip encoding.
2017-01-05 11:05:28,633 - cwlogs.push - INFO - 29223 - MainThread - Using default logging configuration.
```

This makes me think that the configuration probably isn't actually reading/using the datetime_format but I don't understand why it decides to end up using default. I tried to put

```
use_gzip_http_content_encoding = true
```

under general settings, but it doesn't change the errors.

I am running out of ideas - has anyone managed to configure awslogger in a way where the datetime_format is actually used correctly?

Edit:

I'm currently hacking more console logs to local python2.7 push.py to see what is going on :)

---

RESOLVED:

Ok, problem was that I came into this project after the initial setup had been created and I had the impression that the logger was configured to use the .conf file in location:

```
 /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf
```

that was dynamically populated.

The environment had a script that gave this location to awslogs-agent-setup.py which tried to make the agent understand that configuration should be read from here.

However this script didn't actually do what it was supposed to do and when the service started, it actually read the config from

```
/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf
```

Which contained the default values.

So the actual resolution was to change the datetime_format parameter in the default config and forget about the config I thought the service was using.

Comment: I had an EB environment which was using /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf until I rebuilt it, then it started using the /var one instead. This is odd. Did you ever figure out why it was using the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

Add logging to /var/awslogs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py and see how the actual config parameters are interpreted.

You will probably find out that the service is actually using configuration file at default location:

/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf

and hence you have to edit configuration values there for them to be actually read.